# Obtain the eigenfunction of Jz for the wave function of an electron in a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

> The wave function of an electron in a hydrogen atom is given by

[image: Wavefunction]

> 1. Is this wave function an eigenfunction of *Jz* , the *z*-component of the electron’s total angular momentum? If yes, find the eigenvalue. (Hint: For this, you need to calculate Jz Psi21*mlms*.)
> 2. If you measure the *z*-component of the electron’s spin angular momentum, what values will you obtain? What are the corresponding probabilities?
> 3. If you measure J^2, what values will you obtain? What are the corresponding probabilities?

How can I solve this problem or with which rules can be obtains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last spin state is wrong.
It should be $\frac{|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+ |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, to be the $S_z=0$, $S=1$ spin state.

1. The state would then be an eigenstate of $J_z$, with eigenvalue $+1$.
2. Measurements of $S_z$ could be $S_z=0$ ($P=1/3$) and $S_z=+1(P=2/3)$.
3. $J^2=2*3=6$, with $P=1$.